# Plain Text Length Conditional

Tags: conditional

Wondering how to write a conditional that was dependent on the length of a plain text field within a matrix field. I  have something like:

```
{% for block in entry.pricing %}
    <li>{% if block.destination|length > 25 %}TEST{% endif %}{{ block.smallCost }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Where I’m trying to add TEST if the length of the string of block.destination is more than 25.

Comment: That should work as far as I can tell. What happends if you try to output {{ block.destination | length }}?

Comment: It outputs totally fine, giving the length of the string. It’s just the conditional I can’t figure out?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it needs the space in the conditional either side of the vertical bar so the code should’ve been:

```
<li>{% if block.destination | length > 25 %}<br />{% endif %} {{ block.smallCost }}</li>
```

Comment: Really weird... not sure why that would be the case.